# how to write unit test to cover all the condition of breakpoint observer?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable, karma-jasmine, mat-dialog

I try to write unit test breakpoint observer. but the positive condition is not covered

```
 isSmallScreen: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe('(max-width: 767px)');

 openEntityDetailDialog(): void {   
        this.entityCreationComponent.close();
      this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(HomeBusinessEntityDetail, {
        maxWidth: '767px', disableClose: true
      });
   const dialogSubscription = this.isSmallScreen.subscribe(result => {
    if (result.matches) {
      this.dialogRef.updateSize('100%', '100%');
    } else {
      this.dialogRef.updateSize('560px');
    }
  });
 
  this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    dialogSubscription.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TyxR.png)

Help me to write unit test for the line

```
const dialogSubscription = this.isSmallScreen.subscribe(result => {
    if (result.matches) {
      this.dialogRef.updateSize('100%', '100%');
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
it('should update the dialog size', () => {
     component.isSmallScreen = of({ matches: true });
     const spy: Jasmine.Spy = spyOn(component.dialogRef, 'updateSize'); // considering you have mocked the dialogRef in your test
     component.openEntityDetailDialog();
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('100%', '100%');
});
```

Comment: getting error in line "component.isSmallScreen= of({matches:true})". Type 'Observable<{ matches: true; breakpoints: boolean; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<BreakpointState>'.
  Type '{ matches: true; breakpoints: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'BreakpointState'.
    Types of property 'breakpoints' are incompatible.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: boolean; }'.

Comment: try of({ matches: true } as any);